# Bulma.io, center div elements sized in thirds

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm getting back into frontend, so I'm making myself a portfolio page for practice, I'm using the css framework called [Bulma](https://bulma.io) I can't figure out why the "1" on the left isn't centered. I have 4 total divs in the body, 1 to hold the 3 columns, and the 3 columns sized in [thirds](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/)
These are what my divs look like. I didn't feel like making a navbar in traditional CSS, so I used a framework for it. I'm using the repl IDE, [here](https://test-2.vys.repl.co/) is the website where you can view my issue.

I basically just want those 3 divs to be centered, so I can add text in the middle div, labeled as "2". I made the two other divs so I can set some "boundaries".

```
<div class="columns"> <!--defines where the columns are-->
  <div id="left" class="column is-one-third">1</div>
 <div class="column is-one-third">2</div>
 <div class="column is-one-third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your example that the `divs` are centered, but the text inside them is not.

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered">1</div>
 <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered">2</div>
 <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered">3</div>
</div>
```

I centered the text with `has-text-centered` and added a background color to demonstrate:

[image]